# Wrong Data in Month Array

Tags: php, arrays

What I can do  if would like  start my January month since  2016-01-01 not 2016-01-02.

https://3v4l.org/uRRfU

```
  function countDaysForChoosenYears(int $year):int
    {
        $att = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            $att[] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $year);
        }
        $att = array_sum($att);
        return $att;
    }

    $YearMonthDayStructure = [];

    $Date = new DateTime('2016-01-01');


    for ($i = 1; $i <= countDaysForChoosenYears(2016); $i++) {

        $monthName = $Date->format('F');
        $yearNumber = $Date->format('Y');

        $YearMonthDayStructure[$yearNumber][$monthName][$Date->format('d')] = $Date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');

    }

    print_r($YearMonthDayStructure);
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/p2518

Comment: thanks mate...  It is just another order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first time you enter the loop you are adding P1D to the date. So your first date ends up being 2 Jan because you added P1D to 1 Jan on that line with the $Date->add. It's not like $x++ where the '++' happens after you use the variable. It performs the add and then gives the result, with the added P1D, to the $YearMonthDayStructure value.